# Module 'google.cloud.speech_v1p1beta1.types' has no 'RecognitionAudio' member

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-speech-api

Trying to run the sample code and I am getting this error"

```
Module 'google.cloud.speech_v1p1beta1.types' has no 'RecognitionAudio' member
```

Env: python3x, linux, installed and updated google-cloud lib

```
pip install --upgrade google-cloud-speech.
```

Installed the following

- google-cloud (0.34.0)
- google-cloud-speech (0.36.3)

---

Not sure what else to check. Would be great if you have any suggestions

```
import argparse
import io

def transcribe_file_with_enhanced_model():
    """Transcribe the given audio file using an enhanced model."""
    # [START speech_transcribe_enhanced_model_beta]
    from google.cloud import speech_v1p1beta1 as speech
    client = speech.SpeechClient()

    speech_file = 'resources/commercial_mono.wav'

    with io.open(speech_file, 'rb') as audio_file:
        content = audio_file.read()

    audio = speech.types.RecognitionAudio(content=content)

    config = speech.types.RecognitionConfig(
        encoding=speech.enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16,
        sample_rate_hertz=8000,
        language_code='en-US',
        # Enhanced models are only available to projects that
        # opt in for audio data collection.
        use_enhanced=True,
        # A model must be specified to use enhanced model.
        model='phone_call')

    response = client.recognize(config, audio)

    for i, result in enumerate(response.results):
        alternative = result.alternatives[0]
        print('-' * 20)
        print('First alternative of result {}'.format(i))
        print('Transcript: {}'.format(alternative.transcript))
    # [END speech_transcribe_enhanced_model_beta]
```

Comment: I'm seeing this same error on module 'google.cloud.speech_v1.types'

Answer (score 1):

i think your version is "google.cloud.speech_v1" . install the [google-cloud-speech 2.0.0](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-speech/)

> pip uninstall google-cloud-speech

> pip install google-cloud-speech

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
config = {
    "language_code": language_code,
    "sample_rate_hertz": sample_rate_hertz,
    "encoding": encoding,
    "use_enhanced": True,
    "model": 'phone_call',
}
audio = {"uri": storage_uri}
```

Instead of

```
audio = speech.types.RecognitionAudio(content=content)

config = speech.types.RecognitionConfig(
    encoding=speech.enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16,
    sample_rate_hertz=8000,
    language_code='en-US',
    use_enhanced=True,
    model='phone_call')
```